# Telerik RadGrid Export to Excel. Missing operand before '=' operator

Tags: sharepoint, telerik, web-parts, radgrid

I am getting the error 
Missing operand before '=' operator.
when I try and export and the code is running fine in the grid.
Here is the code for the web part.  The error only occurs on the rebind.  It works fine in the grid itself.  Is there any way to narrow down the exact thing it is erroring on?
I am willing to pay for a support / solution to this problem, I just need it to work.

```
[Guid("5fbe4ccf-4d90-476b-af77-347de4e1176c")]
public class ParentChildGrid : Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPart

{


#region
Variables
private bool _error = false;
private string _PageSize = null;
private string _ParentList = null;
private string _ParentView = null;
private string _ParentIDField = null;
private string _FirstChildList = null;
private string _FirstChildView = null;
private string _FirstChildIDField = null;
private string _FirstChildParentIDField = null;
private string _SecondChildList = null;
private string _SecondChildView = null;
private string _SecondChildIDField = null;
private string _SecondChildParentIDField = null;
protected ScriptManager scriptManager;
protected RadAjaxManager ajaxManager;
protected Panel panel;
protected SPView oView;
protected RadGrid oGrid = new RadGrid();
protected Label label;
protected DataTable ParentDataTable;
protected DataTable Child1DataTable;
protected DataTable Child2DataTable;
protected Button cmdExport = new Button();

#endregion
#region
Properties
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.
Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("Items Per Page")]
[WebDescription("# of items to include in each page.")]
public string PageSize
{
    get

    {
        if (_PageSize == null)
        {
            _PageSize = "100";
        }
        return _PageSize.Trim();
    }
    set { _ParentList = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.
Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("ParentList")]
[WebDescription("Parent List in Grid View")]
public string ParentList
{
    get

    {
        if (_ParentList == null)
        {
            _ParentList = "";
        }
        return _ParentList.Trim();
    }
    set { _ParentList = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("ParentView")]
[WebDescription("View for Parent List")]
public string ParentView
{
    get

    {
        if (_ParentView == null)
        {
            _ParentView = "";
        }
        return _ParentView.Trim();
    }
    set { _ParentView = value.Trim(); }
}
[
Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[
WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.
Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[
WebDisplayName("ParentIDField")]
[
WebDescription("ID Field in Parent List")]
public string ParentIDField
{
    get

    {
        if (_ParentIDField == null)
        {
            _ParentIDField = "";
        }
        return _ParentIDField.Trim();
    }
    set { _ParentIDField = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.
Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("FirstChildList")]
[WebDescription("FirstChildList Name")]
public string FirstChildList
{
    get

    {
        if (_FirstChildList == null)
        {
            _FirstChildList = "";
        }
        return _FirstChildList.Trim();
    }
    set { _FirstChildList = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("FirstChildView")]
[WebDescription("First Child View Name")]
public string FirstChildView
{
    get

    {
        if (_FirstChildView == null)
        {
            _FirstChildView = "";
        }
        return _FirstChildView.Trim();
    }
    set { _FirstChildView = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("FirstChildIDField")]
[WebDescription("First Child ID Field (Tyically ID)")]
public string FirstChildIDField
{
    get

    {
        if (_FirstChildIDField == null)
        {
            _FirstChildIDField = "";
        }
        return _FirstChildIDField.Trim();
    }
    set { _FirstChildIDField = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("FirstChildParentIDField")]
[WebDescription("First Child Parent ID Field")]
public string FirstChildParentIDField
{
    get

    {
        if (_FirstChildParentIDField == null)
        {
            _FirstChildParentIDField = "";
        }
        return _FirstChildParentIDField.Trim();
    }
    set { _FirstChildParentIDField = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.
Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("SecondChildList")]
[WebDescription("Second Child List")]
public string SecondChildList
{
    get
    {
        if (_SecondChildList == null)
        {
            _SecondChildList = "";
        }
        return _SecondChildList.Trim();
    }
    set { _SecondChildList = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.
Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("SecondChildView")]
[
WebDescription("Second Child View")]
public string SecondChildView
{
    get
    {
        if (_SecondChildView == null)
        {
            _SecondChildView = "";
        }
        return _SecondChildView.Trim();
    }
    set { _SecondChildView = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.
Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("SecondChildIDField")]
[WebDescription("Second Child ID Field (Typically ID)")]
public string SecondChildIDField
{
    get

    {
        if (_SecondChildIDField == null)
        {
            _SecondChildIDField = "";
        }
        return _SecondChildIDField.Trim();
    }
    set { _SecondChildIDField = value.Trim(); }
}
[Personalizable(PersonalizationScope.Shared)]
[WebBrowsable(true)]
[System.ComponentModel.Category("Parent Child Properties")]
[WebDisplayName("SecondChildParentIDField")]
[WebDescription("Second Child ID Field")]
public string SecondChildParentIDField
{
    get

    {
        if (_SecondChildParentIDField == null)
        {
            _SecondChildParentIDField = "";
        }
        return _SecondChildParentIDField.Trim();
    }
    set { _SecondChildParentIDField = value.Trim(); }
}

#endregion

private const string ByeByeIncludeScriptKey = "myByeByeIncludeScript";
private const string EmbeddedScriptFormat = "&lt;script language=javascript&gt;function ByeBye(){ alert('Test Code'); }&lt;/script&gt; ";
private const string DisableAjaxScriptKey = "myDisableAjaxIncludeScript";
private const string DisableAjaxForExport = "&lt;script language=javascript&gt;function onRequestStart(sender, args) { if (args.get_eventTarget().indexOf(\"cmdExport\") &gt;= 0);args.set_enableAjax(false);alert('Ajax Disabled'); }&lt;/script&gt;";
private void WebPart_ClientScript_PreRender(object sender , System.EventArgs e )
{
    if (!Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(ByeByeIncludeScriptKey))
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(ByeByeIncludeScriptKey,
    EmbeddedScriptFormat);
    if (!Page.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(DisableAjaxScriptKey))
    Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock(DisableAjaxScriptKey,
    DisableAjaxForExport);
    //ajaxManager.ClientEvents.OnRequestStart = "onRequestStart";

}
public ParentChildGrid()
{
    this.ExportMode = WebPartExportMode.All;
    this.PreRender += new EventHandler(WebPart_ClientScript_PreRender);
}
private void onRequestStart()
{
    ajaxManager.EnableAJAX =
    false;
}
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    try

    {
        base.OnInit(e);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(
        typeof(ParentChildGrid), this.ID, "_spOriginalFormAction = document.forms[0].action;_spSuppressFormOnSubmitWrapper=true;", true);
        if (this.Page.Form != null)
        {
            string formOnSubmitAtt = this.Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(formOnSubmitAtt) && formOnSubmitAtt == "return _spFormOnSubmitWrapper();")
            {
                this.Page.Form.Attributes["onsubmit"] = "_spFormOnSubmitWrapper();";
            }
        }
        scriptManager =
        ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
        if (scriptManager == null)
        {
            scriptManager =
            new RadScriptManager();
            this.Page.Form.Controls.AddAt(0, scriptManager);
        }
        scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(cmdExport);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).RegisterPostBackControl(cmdExport);
    if (!_error)
    {
        try

        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            this.EnsureChildControls();
            base.OnLoad(e);
            if (_ParentList != null)
            {
                if (_ParentList != "")
                {
                    panel =
                    new Panel();
                    panel.ID =
                    "Panel1";
                    this.Controls.Add(panel);
                    oGrid =
                    new RadGrid();
                    DefineComplexGrid();
                    oGrid.GridExporting +=
                    new OnGridExportingEventHandler(oGrid_GridExporting);
                    panel.Controls.Add(oGrid);
                    //DefineSimpleMasterDetail();

                    cmdExport.Click +=
                    new EventHandler(cmdExport_Click);
                    cmdExport.Text =
                    "Export";
                    Button cmdExpandAll = new Button();
                    cmdExpandAll.Text =
                    "Expand All";
                    cmdExpandAll.Click +=
                    new EventHandler(cmdExpandAll_Click);
                    panel.Controls.Add(cmdExpandAll);
                    ajaxManager =
                    RadAjaxManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
                    if (ajaxManager == null)
                    {
                        ajaxManager =
                        new RadAjaxManager();
                        ajaxManager.ID =
                        "RadAjaxManager1";
                        Controls.Add(ajaxManager);
                        this.Page.Items.Add(typeof(RadAjaxManager), ajaxManager);
                    }
                    ajaxManager.AjaxSettings.AddAjaxSetting(oGrid, panel);
                    panel.Controls.Add(cmdExport);
                    ajaxManager.AjaxRequest +=
                    new RadAjaxControl.AjaxRequestDelegate(ajaxManager_AjaxRequest);
                    this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br><br>&lt;input class='ms-SPButton' value=\'Test Code\' type=button onclick=\"ByeBye();\" &gt;"));
                    ajaxManager.ClientEvents.OnRequestStart =
                    "onRequestStart";
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex);
        }
    }
}
void oGrid_GridExporting(object source, GridExportingArgs e)
{
    //throw new NotImplementedException();

}
void ajaxManager_AjaxRequest(object sender, AjaxRequestEventArgs e)
{
    ajaxManager.EnableAJAX =
    false;
}
void cmdExpandAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try

    {
        foreach (GridItem item in oGrid.MasterTableView.Items)
        {
            item.Expanded =
            true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
void cmdExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try

    {
        ajaxManager.ClientEvents.OnRequestStart =
        "onRequestStart";
        oGrid.ExportSettings.ExportOnlyData =
        true;
        oGrid.ExportSettings.IgnorePaging =
        true;
        oGrid.ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow =
        true;
        oGrid.MasterTableView.HierarchyDefaultExpanded =
        true;
        if (FirstChildList.Trim() != "")
        oGrid.MasterTableView.DetailTables[0].HierarchyDefaultExpanded =
        true;
        if (SecondChildList.Trim() != "")
        oGrid.MasterTableView.DetailTables[1].HierarchyDefaultExpanded =
        true;
        oGrid.Rebind();
        oGrid.MasterTableView.ExportToExcel();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
//private void DefineSimpleGrid()

//{

    // try

    // {

        // oGrid.ID = "Master";

        // oGrid.PageSize = 10;

        // oGrid.AllowPaging = true;

        // oGrid.AllowSorting = true;

        // oGrid.Skin = "WebBlue";

        // oGrid.GroupingEnabled = true;

        // oGrid.NeedDataSource += new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(oGrid_NeedDataSource);

        // oGrid.ShowStatusBar = true;

        // oGrid.ShowGroupPanel = true;

        // oGrid.GroupingEnabled = true;

        // oGrid.ClientSettings.AllowDragToGroup = true;

        // oGrid.ClientSettings.AllowColumnsReorder = true;

    // }

    // catch (Exception ex)

    // {

        // HandleException(ex);

    // }

//}

private DataTable GetDataTable(String cListName, String ViewName)
{
    try

    {
        SPList list = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[cListName];
        SPView view = list.Views[ViewName];
        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(view);
        if (items != null)
        {
            if (items.Count &gt; 0)
            return items.GetDataTable();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
    return null;
}
//private void DefineSimpleMasterDetail()

//{

    // try

    // {

        // oGrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };

        // oGrid.Skin = "Default";

        // oGrid.Width = Unit.Percentage(100);

        // oGrid.PageSize = 5;

        // oGrid.AllowPaging = true;

        // oGrid.MasterTableView.PageSize = 15;

        // oGrid.MasterTableView.DataSource = GetDataTable(_ParentList, _ParentView);

        // GridTableView tableViewOrders = new GridTableView(oGrid);

        // tableViewOrders.DataSource = GetDataTable(_FirstChildList, _FirstChildView);

        // tableViewOrders.DataKeyNames = new string[] { _ParentIDField };

        // GridRelationFields relationFields = new GridRelationFields();

        // relationFields.MasterKeyField = _FirstChildIDField;

        // relationFields.DetailKeyField = _FirstChildParentIDField;

        // tableViewOrders.ParentTableRelation.Add(relationFields);

        // oGrid.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewOrders);

    // }

    // catch (Exception ex)

    // {

        // HandleException(ex);

    // }

//}

private void DefineComplexGrid()
{
    try

    {
        oGrid.ID =
        "RadGrid1";
        //oGrid.Width = Unit.Percentage(98);

        oGrid.PageSize =
        Convert.ToInt32(PageSize);
        oGrid.AllowPaging =
        true;
        oGrid.AllowSorting =
        true;
        oGrid.PagerStyle.Mode =
        GridPagerMode.NextPrevAndNumeric;
        oGrid.ShowStatusBar =
        true;
        oGrid.ClientSettings.Resizing.AllowColumnResize =
        true;
        oGrid.DetailTableDataBind +=
        new GridDetailTableDataBindEventHandler(oGrid_DetailTableDataBind);
        oGrid.NeedDataSource +=
        new GridNeedDataSourceEventHandler(oGrid_NeedDataSource);
        oGrid.ColumnCreated +=
        new GridColumnCreatedEventHandler(oGrid_ColumnCreated);
        oGrid.MasterTableView.Name = _ParentList;
        if (_FirstChildList != "" || _SecondChildList != "")
        {
            oGrid.MasterTableView.PageSize =
            Convert.ToInt32(PageSize);
            oGrid.MasterTableView.DataKeyNames =
            new string[] { _ParentIDField };
            oGrid.MasterTableView.HierarchyLoadMode =
            GridChildLoadMode.ServerOnDemand;
        }
        if (_FirstChildList != "")
        {
            GridTableView tableViewFirstChild = new GridTableView(oGrid);
            tableViewFirstChild.Width =
            Unit.Percentage(100);
            tableViewFirstChild.HierarchyLoadMode =
            GridChildLoadMode.ServerOnDemand;
            tableViewFirstChild.DataKeyNames =
            new string[] { _FirstChildIDField };
            tableViewFirstChild.Name = _FirstChildList;
            GridRelationFields FirstChildrelationFields = new GridRelationFields();
            FirstChildrelationFields.MasterKeyField = _ParentIDField;
            FirstChildrelationFields.DetailKeyField = _FirstChildParentIDField;
            tableViewFirstChild.ParentTableRelation.Add(FirstChildrelationFields);
            tableViewFirstChild.Caption = _FirstChildList;
            oGrid.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewFirstChild);
        }
        if (_SecondChildList != "")
        {
            GridTableView tableViewSecondChild = new GridTableView(oGrid);
            tableViewSecondChild.Width =
            Unit.Percentage(100);
            tableViewSecondChild.HierarchyLoadMode =
            GridChildLoadMode.ServerOnDemand;
            tableViewSecondChild.DataKeyNames =
            new string[] { _SecondChildIDField };
            tableViewSecondChild.Name = _SecondChildList;
            GridRelationFields SecondChildrelationFields = new GridRelationFields();
            SecondChildrelationFields.MasterKeyField = _ParentIDField;
            SecondChildrelationFields.DetailKeyField = _SecondChildParentIDField;
            tableViewSecondChild.Caption = _SecondChildList;
            tableViewSecondChild.ParentTableRelation.Add(SecondChildrelationFields);
            oGrid.MasterTableView.DetailTables.Add(tableViewSecondChild);
        }
        oGrid.ShowStatusBar =
        true;
        oGrid.ShowGroupPanel =
        true;
        oGrid.GroupingEnabled =
        true;
        oGrid.ClientSettings.AllowDragToGroup =
        true;
        oGrid.ClientSettings.AllowColumnsReorder =
        true;
        oGrid.Skin =
        "Web20";
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
void oGrid_ColumnCreated(object sender, GridColumnCreatedEventArgs e)
{
    try

    {
        //if (e.Column.HeaderText == "ID" || e.Column.HeaderText == "Created")

        //{

            // e.Column.Display = false;

            // return;

        //}

        String cOwnerTable = "";
        cOwnerTable = e.OwnerTableView.Name;
        if (cOwnerTable.Trim() != "" && e.Column.HeaderText != "" && e.Column.HeaderText != _FirstChildParentIDField && e.Column.HeaderText != _SecondChildParentIDField)
        {
            SPList CurrentList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[e.OwnerTableView.Name];
            e.Column.HeaderText = GetFieldDisplayName(e.Column.HeaderText, CurrentList);
            SPField oField = CurrentList.Fields[e.Column.HeaderText];
            GridBoundColumn col = (GridBoundColumn)e.Column;
            switch (oField.Type)
            {
                case SPFieldType.Currency:
                col.DataFormatString =
                "{0:C}";
                break;
                case SPFieldType.DateTime:
                SPFieldDateTime oDateTime = (SPFieldDateTime)oField;
                if (oDateTime.DisplayFormat == SPDateTimeFieldFormatType.DateOnly)
                col.DataFormatString =
                "{0:d}";
                break;
                default:
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
private DataTable GetChildDataTable(GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e, String cChildListName, String cChildView,String cParentIDField)
{
    try

    {
        GridDataItem parentItem = e.DetailTableView.ParentItem as GridDataItem;
        SPList FirstChildList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[cChildListName];
        SPView oView = FirstChildList.Views[cChildView];
        String cContractID = parentItem[_ParentIDField].Text;
        SPQuery oChildQuery = new SPQuery();
        if (Occurs(cParentIDField, oView.Query) == 2)
        {
            String cNewQuery = oView.Query;
            Int32 iPos = cNewQuery.IndexOf(cParentIDField) + cParentIDField.Length;
            String cPartOne = cNewQuery.Substring(0,cNewQuery.IndexOf(cParentIDField, iPos));
            String cPartTwo = cNewQuery.Substring(cNewQuery.IndexOf(cParentIDField, iPos) + cParentIDField.Length);
            cNewQuery = cPartOne + cContractID + cPartTwo;
            oChildQuery.Query = cNewQuery;
            oChildQuery.Query =
            "&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='" + cParentIDField + "' /&gt;&lt;Value Type='Text'&gt;" + cContractID + "&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;";
        }
        else

        {
            oChildQuery.Query =
            "&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='" + cParentIDField + "' /&gt;&lt;Value Type='Text'&gt;" + cContractID + "&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;";
        }
        SPViewFieldCollection oViewFields = oView.ViewFields;
        oViewFields.Add(cParentIDField);
        String cViewFields = oViewFields.SchemaXml;
        oChildQuery.ViewFields = cViewFields;
        SPListItemCollection items = FirstChildList.GetItems(oChildQuery);
        if (items != null)
        {
            if (items.Count &gt; 0)
            {
                return items.GetDataTable();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //HandleException(ex);

    }
    return null;
}
void oGrid_DetailTableDataBind(object source, GridDetailTableDataBindEventArgs e)
{
    try

    {
        GridDataItem parentItem = e.DetailTableView.ParentItem as GridDataItem;
        if (parentItem.Edit)
        {
            return;
        }
        if (e.DetailTableView.Name == _FirstChildList)
        {
            Child1DataTable = GetChildDataTable(e, _FirstChildList, _FirstChildView, _FirstChildParentIDField);
            e.DetailTableView.DataSource = Child1DataTable;
        }
        if (e.DetailTableView.Name == _SecondChildList)
        {
            Child2DataTable = GetChildDataTable(e, _SecondChildList, _SecondChildView, _SecondChildParentIDField);
            e.DetailTableView.DataSource = Child2DataTable;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
void oGrid_NeedDataSource(object source, GridNeedDataSourceEventArgs e)
{
    try

    {
        if (!e.IsFromDetailTable)
        {
            SPList ParentList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[_ParentList];
            oView = ParentList.Views[_ParentView];
            SPQuery ParentQuery = new SPQuery();
            ParentQuery.Query = oView.Query;
            ParentQuery.RowLimit = 100000;
            ParentQuery.ViewFields = oView.ViewFields.SchemaXml;
            SPListItemCollection oItems = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists[_ParentList].GetItems(ParentQuery);
            ParentDataTable = oItems.GetDataTable();
            oGrid.DataSource = ParentDataTable;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
}
private string GetFieldDisplayName(String cInternalName, SPList oList)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (SPField field in oList.Fields)
        {
            if (field.InternalName == cInternalName)
            return field.Title;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
    return cInternalName;
}
private Int32 Occurs(String SearchFor, String SearchIn)
{
    Int32 Count = 0;
    Int32 iPos = 0;
    try
    {
        while (SearchIn.IndexOf(SearchFor, iPos) != -1)
        {
            Count++;
            iPos = SearchIn.IndexOf(SearchFor, iPos) + 1;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        HandleException(ex);
    }
    return Count;
}
private void HandleException(Exception ex)
{
    this._error = true;
    try
    {
        this.Controls.Clear();
        this.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(ex.Message));
    }
    catch
    {
    }
}
} //End Class
```

Comment: It might have something to do with your child datatables. It's a wild guess though.

Doesn't the exception tell you anything?

Comment: What I would do is to post the code from the CreateChildControls method as well as the export logic either here or in the Telerik forums to get more to-the-point answer. Dick

Answer (score 1):

As a follow-up, it appears the problem was that there were `NULL` values in John's original data. These nulls were causing problems during the data export. Fixing the null values also fixed the Excel export. Original solution on Telerik.com forums:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/extremely-frustrated-please-help-with-radgrid-export-of-multi-tabe-view.aspx